# Why should server actions add `user server` directive on top of the server action function?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

Just as the next.js documentation says, by default, next.js use server component, but from the server actions documatation's server components part, the server actions in the server component should add 'use server' directive.

[image]

My confusion part is that as the default component type in next.js is server side component, why the server actions in it should add 'use server' directives?

Comment: Without the `"use server"` directive next is free to execute the component on the browser. The default is just a default - it doesn't mean that's what it is when you actually mount the component. With the `"use server"` directive React will hopefully throw an error if the component ever gets executed in the browser.

Comment: I think the poster is asking specifically about Server Actions in Server Components where no **browser** exist

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a very good question.

Even though you define the Server Action within a Server Component, it cannot be executed directly within it.

Let's consider this Server Action:

```
export default function Page() {
  async function action(formAction) {
    "use server";

    // ...
  }

  return // ...
}
```

Where would you invoke this function?

You have two options:

1. Pass it as a prop to a client component:

```
export default function Page() {
  return <ClientComponent action={action} />
}
```

```
// client.ts
"use client";

function ClientComponent({ action }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // for example,
    action()
  }, [])

  // or
 
  return <form action={action}>
}
```

In this case, the Server Action is utilized on the client.

2. Pass it to a **Client** HTML element like `<form />`

```
return <form action={action}>{/* ... */}</form>
// or 
return <button formAction={action}>
```

Yes, you've read it correctly. HTML Elements are considered Client Components "because only the browser 'knows' what they mean and can take them to completion (showing things on the screen)" as Dan Abramov [explained](https://x.com/dan_abramov2/status/1751715608226304499?s=20) (React Core Team).

These are the ways you can execute the Server Action, and all of them are utilized on the Client side.

If you assume you could call them directly within the Server Component like:

```
export default function Page() {
  async function getUser(formAction) {
    "use server";

     return db.users.findFirst(...)
  }

  // Call here or in another server component
  const user = await getUser();

  return // ...
}
```

No, you can't. Next.js will throw an error indicating that you can't use a Server Action during rendering.

---

The `"use server"` directive tells the bundler to generate a POST endpoint (like tRPC Mutations). It marks a communication gateway between the Client Component (e.g., `<form />`) and the Server.